# Methods of altering the angle of a projectile launch tube

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Given some desired release angle, could someone please suggest a way that a machine could alter the angle of a launch tube per feed back from an ultrasonic sensor (I've derived the relation between range and desired angle separately, but is not really necessary here). I'm not looking for an extremely detailed description, but rather some broad outline on a method.

Comment: if you have the sensor, the other part is the actuator.  power source? fuel (chemical reaction)=engine.  electricity or pressurized fluid=motor.  as for mechanical conversion, take your pick based on other constraints such as available space and actuator power - gears cams pulleys screws all have advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A screw thread would work, use the sensor to drive a motor with suitable gearing.

Comment: Use a worm driven gear for all axis of pivot and you will have a linear relationship between screw rotation and angular displacement.